# AVM package not loading

Tags: avm

I'm trying to use the `avm` package. However, when I try to load `\usepackage(avm)` the pdf breaks down right from the start and I get the error message

> "File 'avm.sty' not found".

Any idea what might be going wrong? (Probably some rather trivial error, sorry.)

Comment: the error message is quite clear isn't it? You don't have this sty (I haven't it either). Why do you believe that it should be in your tex system?

Comment: texlive has no package called avm. Wherever you saw this documented presumably said where it came from?

Comment: google avm.sty suggests it is in from https://www1.essex.ac.uk/linguistics/external/clmt/latex4ling/archive/avm.sty.gz  you  just need to get that uncomress it and save it next to your document